# Corel Paradox ODBC Driver

Tags: delphi, odbc, paradox, bde

I am in the process of migrating some legacy software that uses Delphi (XE3 or Tokyo) and the BDE against Paradox.

We will be going with UniDAC, and have the software running, using ODBC (MS Paradox Driver).  Unfortunately, the MS Drivers are incomplete, we frequently get messages stating that some particular *optional* function is not available.  Things like post should not be optional.  :)

We own Corel Paradox 9.0.  I just installed that hoping to find the official Corel ODBC Drivers would appear in my ODBCAdmin, but they did not.  I went further and installed the Paradox 9 SDK, and then the Paradox 9 RunTime.  Still the Corel ODBC Driver is not appearing in my ODBC Admin.  Is there some extra step?

Based on what I have been told by other devs, the ODBC Drivers should have automatically populated after installing Paradox itself.  The documentation is of no help and articles are few and far between.

Can someone tell me how to access the ODBC Paradox Driver from Corel?  Alternatively, is there another way to hookup Delphi to Paradox, without ODBC (or the BDE)?  I have searched, but not found any other way.  FYI, eventually we will be going to SQLite, but we do still need paradox.

Thank you!

***EDIT***

Another approach... if anyone has this installed already, but doesn't know where it came from, Eg, some runtime library, one could open the ODBC Admin and the driver will point to the underlying dll.  Just getting me the name of the dll would be very helpful.

Thank you, again.

Comment: Even Microsoft's ODBC driver for Paradox  **requires** the BDE according to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/paradox-driver-programming-considerations?view=sql-server-ver15.  I very much doubt that you will find any 3rd party driver that can access PDox tables.  Ymmv but IMO your time would be better spent getting off PDox completely than chasing "optional features" of whatever sort.

Comment: It is an optional component in the installer from what I remember. Also make sure to check both the 32 and 64 bit ODBC control panels (Windows control panel, search for ODBC, on 64 bit Windows should see both a "Set up ODBC data sources (32-bit)" and one for (64-bit).

Comment: Btw, if you are only interested in reading PDox tables so you can move the, to another format. you might take a look at the SMImport library [here](http://www.scalabium.com/)

Comment: @brian I take it you no longer have it installed?

Comment: No longer installed. Might be worth installing a trial of the latest Corel Office Professional and seeing if there is any option to install the Paradox ODBC driver and where it puts it etc.